# Removing a merged column in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, duplicates

I have a merged column of "name_id" in the left as it shown below. I have used `df=df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]` also but did not remove it. Any ideas? thanks.

[image]

Comment: That's not a column, that's an index, or possibly a multiindex, it's hard to tell. Please [edit] your question to include your sample input as text in the body of the question, not as an image or link, to make a [mcve]. Try `set_index()` or `reset_index()` as places to start

Comment: `time_series_df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: `df=df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]` doesn't work because the first `name_id` is an index, not a column. I posted an answer. Check it out and let me know if there was a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
time_series_df.droplevel(0)
```

You'll have a multi-index after a groupby. You can drop that column as above.

Comment: Thanks Ali jan! this one works better!

Comment: sure I did! sorry I am new here. You too!

Answer (score 2):

**if you want to delete the merged rows name_id**

the name_id on the left has been set as index. try to reset it first:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=0)
```

then try to remove duplicates again

**if you want to delete the name_id column with value in each row**

```
df= df.drop(df.columns['name_id'], axis = 1)
```

Comment: `df= df.drop(df.columns['name_id'], axis = 1)` raises an error. It should be something like: `df= df.drop('name_id', axis = 1)`